# 2 different collations conflict when merging tables with Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation, nvarchar

I have  `DB1` which has a *Hebrew* collation

I also have  `DB2` which has *latin* general collation.

I was asked to merge a table (write a query) between `DB1.dbo.tbl1` and `DB2.dbo.tbl2`

I *could* write in the wuqery

```
insert into ...SELECT Col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS...
```

But I'm *sick* of doing it.

I want to make both dbs/tables to the *same* collation  so I don't have to write every time `COLLATE...`

The question is  -

Should I convert `latin->hebrew` **or** `Hebrew->latin` ?

we need to store everything from everything. ( and all our text column are `nvarachr(x)`)

And if so , How do I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Unicode data types in resulted database - `nvarchar(x)`, then you are to omit `COLLATE` in `INSERT`. SQL Server will convert data from your source collation to Unicode automatically. So you should not convert anything if you are inserting to `nvarchar` column.

Comment: thanks. still if I want to have 1 collation ,Should I convert latin->hebrew or Hebrew->latin ?

Comment: Most probably you should use hebrew collaton because latin symbols are subset of hebrew codepage. But again, using Unicode data types doesn't require neither 'converting' nor writing `COLLATE` in your code.

Comment: _latin symbols are subset of hebrew codepage_--from where did you get that info ? should hebrew codepages contains latin symbols ?

Comment: To be honest I don't know much about hebrew language support. My conclusion is the result of quick investigation of hebrew codepages I found - [Windows-1255](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) and [ISO/IEC 8859-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-8).